# How to get parameters from link sent to Facebook Notifications

Tags: spring-social, spring-social-facebook

Not sure how to ask this question. I have implemented a ConnectInterceptor. However, I don't think it will have the parameters that are in the link sent to a user in their Facebook notifications.

Here is the scenario. A user is logged into our application (Facebook Flash app, iOS app, Android etc. Doesn't matter) The user has connected their Facebook account to their login. Now they go to a page that shows all their friends on Facebook where they can send an invite to that friend to join our app (signup). In that invite that we send to the friend's notifications has the userID (our app) and a gift/productID in the link that will take the user to our app in Facebook where they can join. When they join, it will connect their Facebook account to our app, and at that time we have to give free chips to the user that invited the Facebook Friend (hence the userID in the link) and give any gift to the new user (hence the gift/productID) in the link sent to their notifications.

So I need access to the userID and gift/productID when creating the new user in our app. New user is created in a ConnectionSignUp implementation. But that has execute(Connection) which will definitely not have the user and gift IDs in the call.

Basically, in our app we have players inviting Facebook friends to join the game, and if they do the player inviting will get free chips and the new player might get a gift or free chips, but only when the new player signs up/links their Facebook account in our app.

So I thought an interceptor would be able to get it from the

`void postConnect(Connection<T> tConnection, WebRequest webRequest)` call.

Will that work, or is there another way to implement this use case that we need.

Thanks

Mark

Comment: The interceptor is actually perfect for this scenario, and made the whole implementation extremely easy. Very nice that the Spring Social team added all those interceptors for different scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments for answer. Interceptors is the way to go